# How to make API calls in React's Component one by one?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Disclaimer: I'm not a frontend-developer, so the question below may look stupid or it's posed in a wrong way. Please don't be too strict.

I try rendering a Grid from `react-bootstrap`, it contains this piece of code:

```html
...
<tbody>
    {
        this.state.projects.map((project,i)=>{
            return(
                <tr key={i}>
                    <th>{project.label}</th>
                    <td><ObjectCount data_url={`/api/foo/?type=1&project_id=${project.value}`} /></td>
                    <td><ObjectCount data_url={`/api/foo/?type=2&project_id=${project.value}`} /></td>
                    <td><ObjectCount data_url={`/api/foo/?type=3&project_id=${project.value}`} /></td>
                    <td><ObjectCount data_url={`/api/foo/?type=4&project_id=${project.value}`} /></td>
                    <td><ObjectCount data_url={`/api/foo/?type=6&project_id=${project.value}`} /></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
</tbody>
...
```

So the code above iterates over projects and makes API calls to fetch data for different types.
The problem is that there are 1k projects, so the code makes `1000 projects x 6 types = 6000 requests` at a time, and our backend just cannot handle such amount of requests.

Here is the ObjectCount component code:

```js
class ObjectCount extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            data: {results:[]},
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        var Host = Settings.Host;
        if (this.props.data_url){
            if (this.props.data_url.indexOf("?") !== -1){
                var url = Host + this.props.data_url + "&format=json"
            }
            else{
                url = Host + this.props.data_url + "?format=json"
            }
            axios.get(url,{
                headers: {
                    "Authorization":"Token " + cookie.load('token',{ path: '/' })
                }
            })
                .then(res =>{
                    const data = res.data;
                    this.setState({ data });
                    this.setState({ loading: false });
            })
                .catch(res =>{
                if (res.response.status === 401){
                    cookie.remove("token", { path: '/' });
                    cookie.remove("email", { path: '/' });
                    window.location.assign('/');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    render (){
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (<span>{Settings.Loading}</span>);
        }
        else{
            return (<span>{this.state.data.count}</span>);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make each API call one by one? Maybe using a queue, for example we make only 100 requests at a time and the rest wait in the queue? Or at least add a delay after each call?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: in my opinion the best thing to do here would be to make a single API request to fetch all the data you need at once - perhaps with parameters in the query string indicating precisely which data you want to fetch. I realise this may well mean a complete rewrite of your backend API but surely that's better than making thousands of separate requests for each client, even if you can devise some "queue" system as you're asking. (Which while not impossible would be very complex for something that is imo only a "sticking plaster" solution.)

Comment: This is definitely a problem related to API design. You might find it useful to check out [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) or other systems which allow for requests which support some kind of query payload. If modifying the API is not a possibility, then you'll need to implement a pattern which loads groups of results at a time instead of all of them at once (e.g. [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination), lazy-loaded results as you scroll, etc.).

Comment: Yes it like loading a pagniated list, each request need to indicate if new requests can be made, and then it can make recursive api call

Comment: I agree with the things mentioned above. However, if you really need to fix it in your way you could use two techniques. 
1) wrap all the components in a context and have the context handle (and throttle) the requests for you and returned the promised results to the corresponding components. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
2) another option could be utilizing react-query and make this in control of your requests as it handles a lot of the above mentioned optimizations https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query